# How to increase contrast of a black and white image?

Tags: image-processing

I receive scanned documents that I need to increase contrast to print. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `gimp` to increase the contrast. Select the dropdown menu *Colors* and one of the methods, for example *Brightness/Contrast* or *Curves*. This works for single or few pictures/pages.
- The package `imagemagick` provides batch tools (if there are many pictures/pages). There are several good tutorials, for example

  [www.imagemagick.org/Usage/](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)

Answer (score 0):

**Image-magic** is a good software for editing batch pictures and You can also use ** GIMP** it is free and it work almost like adobe photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

With **Shotwell viewer** you can easily increase contrast on images.

Click on the *Adjust* button on the bottom of the program

[image]

and decrease the *Highlights* level.

[image]